# Missing file written on external drive

Tags: c, linux, file, copy

I'm creating an application to copy certain files from our ubuntu server to an external hdd (formatted using ntfs) for backup and most of those files size are more than 4GB.
The problem was sometimes some of the files are missing (not all files and not every occasion).

These are my code:

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
size_t size;

int source = open(c_fileName, O_RDONLY, 0);
int dest = open(c_targetFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT /*| O_TRUNC/**/, 0644);

while ((size = read(source, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0) {
    write(dest, buf, size);
    *progress+=size;
}

close(source);
close(dest);
```

I have tried to check the file is exists and the size is the same, after the application finished writing using this code:

```
if (fsource = fopen(c_targetFile, "rb")) {
    isSourceFileExists=true;
    // check file size
    fseek (fsource, 0, SEEK_END);   // non-portable
    size=ftell(fsource);
    fclose(fsource);
}else{
    isSourceFileExists=false;
    size=0;
}
```

But the problem is sometimes I can't find the file using other computer.

Comment: For production code always test the result of all relevant calls for error!

Comment: To simply copy around files I'd go for a shell script.

Comment: Especially if you're worried about the behaviour of the the program, you need to check the results from `open()`, `write()`, and `close()` — as well as `read()` which you are checking.

Comment: `read()` returns `ssize_t` btw, not `size_t`.

Comment: Yesterday, it happen again and i already check using ls and the file is there. But today when I open it at home, I realize it's missing a file out of 24 files.

Comment: If you think you are missing files but the others are looking okay, the more likely source of errors is the logic by which your program decides what files to copy.  But that is neither visible in the above code, nor is it clear what files do you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

> Yesterday, it happen again and i already check using ls and the file
>   is there. But today when I open it at home, I realize it's missing a
>   file out of 24 files.

If a file *is there* first and *missing* after plugging the HDD in at another place (or powering down and up), you probably just didn't **unmount** the drive properly.